# Writing Arabic in CSV file using Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csv, unicode, arabic, tweepy

Consider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import json

import unicodecsv as csv
import pandas as pd
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open('tweets.txt', "r")

for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)

        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue
tweets_file1 = open('tweets.csv', "wb")
tweets_file_writer = csv.writer(tweets_file1, encoding='utf-8')
tweets_file_writer.writerow(['location', 'time', 'user_id', 'text', 'hashtags', 'user_mentions'])
for i in tweets_data:
    location = unicode(i[u'user'][u'location']).encode('utf-8')
    time = unicode(i[u'created_at']).encode('utf-8')
    user_id = unicode(i[u'user'][u'id']).encode('utf-8')
    text = unicode(i[u'text']).encode('utf-8')
    hashtag = i[u'entities'][u'hashtags']
    hashtags = []
    for j in hashtag:
        print j[u'text']
        hashtags.append(u''.join(j[u'text']).encode('utf-8'))


    mention = i[u'entities'][u'user_mentions']
    mentions = []
    for j in mention:
        mentions.append(unicode(j[u'screen_name']).encode('utf-8'))

    tweets_file_writer.writerow([location, time, user_id, text,  hashtags, mentions])
tweets_file1.close()
```

I wrote this code for scraping some Arabic data using tweepy.

My problem is in this line
`tweets_file_writer.writerow([location, time, user_id, text,  hashtags, mentions])` when adding hashtags list it does not appear in Arabic,
although the other all data appears normally.

Example:

In a CSV file I need to write a hashtag list like:

> ['مجلة_النجوم2', 'سهيله_بن_لشهب', 'souhilabenlachhab']

It appears like this:

> ['\xd9\x85\xd8\xac\xd9\x84\xd8\xa9_\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x86\xd8\xac\xd9\x88\xd9\x852',
>   '\xd8\xb3\xd9\x87\xd9\x8a\xd9\x84\xd9\x87_\xd8\xa8\xd9\x86_\xd9\x84\xd8\xb4\xd9\x87\xd8\xa8',
>   'souhilabenlachhab']

Comment: As an aside, python 3's unicode support is much more robust than 2.x. Don't write 2.x unless you are absolutely stuck with it.

Comment: unfortunately it's a homework task

Comment: Too bad. You'd think teachers would kinda keep up with this type of thing. That's utf-8 data in a string, so the question is how it got there. I believe its actually in the read of the json doc. Try `tweets_file = codecs.open('tweets.txt', "r", encoding="utf-8")`. ... and let me know if that works.

Comment: the same results

Comment: Sorry about being late gettting back... a smaller example I can test may help. Is this on windows? Where exactly does that list show up? Was it a print in your code or did it quite literally show up that way in the csv? I tried a small json file `['مجلة_النجوم2', 'سهيله_بن_لشهب', 'souhilabenlachhab']` and wrote 1 csv line without problem. If you can cut this down to something small and testable, it would help!

Comment: Okay, I spent so much time looking at encoding issues that i missed the obvious. `hashtags = []` ... hashtags is a list and when you write it as a cell to the csv, python takes the `str` of the list... which is that blob you see.

Comment: Leading to the next question... when you have multiple hashtags, how do you want that to look in the csv? You could do `','.join(hashtags)` and let csv escape those commas or pick another separator such as space or semicolo.

Comment: i replaced `hashtages=[]` by `hashtages=str('')`
then  I edited this line 
`hashtags.append(u''.join(j[u'text']).encode('utf-8'))`
to `hashtags+=str(j[u'text'].encode('utf-8'))+str(' ')`
and it works now

Comment: now I want to read all hashtages from my CSV file 
and put them in list or set 
`hashtags = []
mentions =[]
for row in readFile:
    number_of_records +=1
    temp = map(str,row[4].split())
    for i in temp:
        hashtags.append(i)
    temp = map(str, row[5].split())
    for i in temp:
        mentions.append(i)`
printing hashtages list appears like
`['\xd8\xb9\xd9\x85\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88_\xd8\xaf\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa8']`

Comment: I think the problem appears with lists

Comment: I don't think you need those `.encode('utf-8')` calls to strings that will go to the `unicodecsv` writer. That's the writer's job. Instead of the hashtags change, you could just do `u' '.join(hashtags)` while writing. Then reading, once you get the hashtag column, just do `hashtags = hashtags.split(' ')`. At the end, try `for tag in hashtags: print tag` to see if it looks right.

Comment: it works finally !
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file you're going to write to as a utf-8 encoded file before trying to write Arabic to it, so:

```
tweets_file1 = open("tweets.csv", "wb")
```

should be:

```
import codecs
tweets_file1 = codecs.open("tweets.csv", "wb", "utf-8")
```

And, as others mentioned, once you're not stuck with Python2, using Python3 makes working with Arabic *so* much easier!